# If a data table a class and records are objects, what about joins?

Tags: php, database, oop, orm

I know in php its a good practice to have database tables in class. So,

```
$myTable = new DbTable_Users();
$res = $myTable->doQuery();
.
.
$res->getID();
$res->getNAME();
```

but if I see a result set, there can be JOIN, so mixed fields. A class can't extends 2 classes. Then how to dodge this?

```
$res = Factory::doQuery ('SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID');
// A fields => ID, FIELD1, FIELD2
// B fields => ID, DATE, FIELD2

$res->getID();    - **now which field?? A.ID or B.ID** ??
```

Comment: Can you show a little example too?

Comment: **offtopic:** _A class can't extends 2 classes._ `class first {}` then `class second extends first {}` then `class third extends second {}`.. ta da, third class extends two classes

Answer (score 1):

There are various methods of designing so-called compound models (where some fields might be actually related to another tables).

The most clear way, as for me, is to design database tables/mappers as classes of one type, but domain models as classes of another type; the latter would *use* the former as building blocks.

Answer (score 1):

My own opinion on how this type of data should be treated and organized:

Your `DbTable_Users` object should be a `User` object. It should contain the information about one user (presumably one row of data in the database). You may want to have a `Users` (plural) object for a collection of user objects. However, `array($user1, $user2, $user3)` might work for you just fine.

Let's assume you have a `Post` object for postings made by the user. And, you want to get all the postings made by a user with all their information. Normally, this would be some sort of join query:

```
SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id WHERE users.id = 1;
```

Internally, this would create a single `User` object and multiple `Post` objects to represent the data returned from the join. You would access this information via `$user->posts`.